# If statement python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have this here written in python and I would like to know how can I stop the code from continuing until its true. This is a part of a code from a GUI and when I click the button and I haven't written anyting in the textbox this returns an error, in this case saying invalid email and password but right now when I do it it continues to the rest of the code. How can I avoid it and make it stay I click the button only when there's some input on the textbox?

```
def sign_up_clicked_r():
    global inv_user
    global inv_pass
    user = user_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()

    if not user:
        inv_user = canvas.create_text(
            252.0, 259.0, text="Invalid Email Address!", fill="#9f0000",
            font=("Poppins Regular", int(11.0 * -1.1)), anchor="nw")
    else:
        canvas.after(1750, nextpage)

    if not password:
        inv_pass = canvas.create_text(
            252.0, 340.0, text="Invalid Password!", fill="#9f0000",
            font=("Poppins Regular", int(11.0 * -1.1)), anchor="nw")
    else:
        canvas.after(1750, nextpage)

    password = hash_password(password)

    with open('user_data.data', 'a') as file:
        file.write(f'{user},{password}\n')
    user_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)
    canvas.create_text(
        252.0, 340.0, text="Registration Successful!", fill="#41BC66",
        font=("Poppins Regular", int(11.5 * -1.1)), anchor="nw")
    canvas.after(2000, registration_success)
```

**EDIT:** I don't know if using the while function was the best idea but when I did it ended up crashing the program, not sure if I used it correctly though. I am also a bit new into this.

Comment: adding `return` to any part of a function will stop it. e.g. `if not user and not password: return`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **boolean variable** that changes when the conditions are not appropriate.

- `valid_state` changes to `False` when there is an invalid email or password.
- if `valid_state` is `True` - it will open the file etc. if it is `False`, it will skip that section of code.

For example:

#### Code:

```
def sign_up_clicked_r():
    global inv_user
    global inv_pass
    user = user_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    valid_state = True

    if not user:
        inv_user = canvas.create_text(
            252.0, 259.0, text="Invalid Email Address!", fill="#9f0000",
            font=("Poppins Regular", int(11.0 * -1.1)), anchor="nw")
        valid_state = False
    else:
        canvas.after(1750, nextpage)

    if not password:
        inv_pass = canvas.create_text(
            252.0, 340.0, text="Invalid Password!", fill="#9f0000",
            font=("Poppins Regular", int(11.0 * -1.1)), anchor="nw")
        valid_state = False
    else:
        canvas.after(1750, nextpage)
    
    # The following code will only execute if the valid_state is True
    if valid_state:
        password = hash_password(password)

        with open('user_data.data', 'a') as file:
            file.write(f'{user},{password}\n')
        user_entry.delete(0, END)
        password_entry.delete(0, END)
        canvas.create_text(
            252.0, 340.0, text="Registration Successful!", fill="#41BC66",
            font=("Poppins Regular", int(11.5 * -1.1)), anchor="nw")
        canvas.after(2000, registration_success)
```

Comment: to make code readable avoid using indentation as much as possible. e.g. rather than `if valid: do_code` change it around to `if not valid: return \n do_code` it just makes for cleaner looking code and is much easier to follow.